# Object in Three.js code is always rendered on top of another

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to JavaScript and Three.js, and I have written some code here to render a sphere (Earth) and another smaller sphere (Satellite) in orbit. The problem I am having is that when the satellite passes behind the Earth, it is still visible on top of the Earth.

```js
// Create Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// Create Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100.0 * R_earth );
camera.position.z = 4.0 * R_earth;
camera.position.y = 1.0 * R_earth;
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
scene.add(camera);

// Earth Mesh
const earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(R_earth, 32, 32);
const earth_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x999999} );
const earth_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom, earth_mat);
scene.add(earth_mesh);

// Satellite Mesh
const sat = new Satellite(2.0 * R_earth, 0.0, Math.PI/2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const sat_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1 * R_earth, 32, 32);
const sat_mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
const sat_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sat_geom, sat_mat);
scene.add(sat_mesh);

// Ambient Light Source
const ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xf1f1f1, 1);
scene.add(ambient_light);

// Spot Light Source
const spot_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
spot_light.position.set(100*R_earth,100*R_earth,100*R_earth);
scene.add(spot_light);

// Render loop
var t = 0.0;
function render() {
    t += 100.0;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    const sat_pos = sat.position(t);
    sat_mesh.position.x = sat_pos.get([0]);
    sat_mesh.position.y = sat_pos.get([1]);
    sat_mesh.position.z = sat_pos.get([2]);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

The `Satellite` class is written in another file, but all it does is provide the orbit mechanics equations to get the position vector of the Satellite at time `t`. I have verified that the satellite object does indeed pass behind the Earth, so I don't think it is a problem with the actual positions of the objects in space.

I tried to search for this problem an found references to the concept of render order, which I am kind of familiar with now (I have no background in computer graphics), but all the posts I found were about forcing the render order in a certain way, i.e. making one objects always on top of another. Here, I seem to be having the opposite problem, I need the satellite to be hidden by the Earth, but it is not.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue in an editable live example? I've adapted your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pzy3L256/) and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @Mugen87, I downloaded your version from JSFiddle and ran it locally on my computer, and I have the same problem, which makes me think that its not a problem with the code itself, but the environment I am running it in. I am on MacOS, and I've tried FireFox and Safari.

Comment: I'm using an iMac with macOS 10.15.4. I've verified that the code works with Chrome 81.0.4044.129, FF 75 and Safari 13.1. Are you on the latest OS version?

Comment: I made a mistake downloading your code the first time, because I did it again and it works on my machine. I found the problem to be my definition of the radius of the Earth as ```const R_earth = 6.371009e6;```. When I use Earth radius of one, it works, but when I use the actual value in meters, there is the problem. My guess is that since I am defining a lot of values as multiples of this variable, and since it is a large value, there might be some numerical problems. I will use km, or AU to reduce the magnitude of the values. I will add an answer to this post with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem to be the value of the radius of the Earth. I had defined this in meters as

```
const R_earth = 6.371009e6;
```

Since a lot of the parameters in the code are multiples of this number, there may be a numerical issue. I found that by using smaller values, like by using kilometers instead of meters, the issue is resolved.

Thanks to @Mugen87 for helping.